# make python 2.7 tkinter gui to an executable

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, py2exe, cx-freeze

i'm trying to make an executable file from my Tkinter gui.py.

i searched for the solution and i found py2exe and cx_freeze.

both of them gave me the same error which is:

```
---------------------------
cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
exec(code, m.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\omris\PycharmProjects\tools\ctrlC_gui.py", line 12, in <module>
import excel_zeros_mail as ezm
File "C:\Users\omris\PycharmProjects\tools\excel_zeros_mail.py", line 3, in <module>
import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\api.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.io.gbq import read_gbq
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\gbq.py", line 44, in <module>
    _GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_VERSION = pkg_resources.get_distribution('google-api-python-client').version
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 332, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 212, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 741, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 626, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
DistributionNotFound: google-api-python-client

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

this is my setup.py code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=["analyst_gui.py"])
```

i tested it on a very simple tkinter gui and it worked well.

my guess it's connected to pandas import?

this is my imports in the tkinter gui:

```
   import threading
   from Tkinter import *
   import tkMessageBox
   from ttk import *
   import pyperclip
   import time
   from tkFileDialog import *
   import pandas as pd
```

i went to the code the makes the problem which located at pkg_resources.py:

```
if dist is None:
       #msg = ("The '%s' distribution was not found on this "
       #       "system, and is required by this application.")
       #raise DistributionNotFound(msg % req)
       # unfortunately, zc.buildout uses a str(err)
       # to get the name of the distribution here..
       raise DistributionNotFound(req)
```

i can't find out what is the problem

my google-api-python-client version is 1.3.1

my pandas version is 0.15.2

Comment: after i comment all my pandas rows, it worked.. is there any problem with making exe while using pandas library?